# Render two ejs pages in layout.js

Tags: javascript, express, layout, ejs

I am trying to understand the working of `express-ejs-layouts`. Basically what I have understood about `layout.js` is that it is used to render ejs pages that have some common content, like javascript. I have made two different ejs templates,`homepage.js` and `dashboard.js` which have `<h1 id="heading1"></h1>` and `<h1 id="heading"></h1>` respectively, as their content.

Below is `layout.js` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <%- body %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Hello, There!!";
            document.getElementById("heading1").innerHTML = "Homepage";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am rendering it the two templates like this:

```
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('dashboard');
})

app.get('/homepage',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('homepage');
})
```

When I hit `/`, I see the `h1` tag, but when I hit `/homepage`, I don't see anything and on console, I see an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')` in `layout.js`. Basically, when homepage is rendered, it cannot find the h1 tag of dashboard.

Am I implementing the layout in correct way? Or is there any mistake in my logic?
Please help me to find the way to solve the problem.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

> Am I implementing the layout in correct way?

No.

The layout file is supposed to contain the elements that are **common** to all pages.

You have two bits of client-side JavaScript, each of which is **specific** to a different page.

`dashboard.ejs` and `homepage.ejs` should know their own titles because that is information specific to those files.

Comment: Thats fine, but how do I populate the headings of two templates from same layout page

Comment: You don't! That's my point. Your h1 tags are in `dashboard.ejs` and `homepage.ejs`. The headings are specific to those pages. Just type the text into the elements in those files. `layout.ejs` is irrelevant at this point. (It wouldn't be if the `<h1>` tags were in `layout.ejs` and you wanted to pass the data to it from the specific page files, but that isn't the case.